# Parse.com withinMiles and withinKilometers not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, coordinates, distance

I don't have any problem on building or running my app. I stored on Parse a geopoint and I am comparing with another one created in-running.

Distance between them is 1 meter.

This doesn't return any point:

`query.whereKey("Coordinate", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinKilometers: 15.0)`

This returns that 1 meter far point:

```
query.whereKey("Coordinate", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation)
```

And this returns that 1 meter far point:`

`query.whereKey("Coordinate", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinKilometers: 155555555.0)`

Why is this happenning? Thanks